# Modal sign up form with php validation

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I was designing some websites and i ran into a problem which was how to create a bootstrap modal sign up form which overlays the page when the sign up button is clicked and also ran some php validations in the form showing errors when necessary. My major problem was when the submit button is clicked on the modal form no validation takes place. I do not want to use the client side validation because i learnt is not safe. I would be glad if someone puts me through this problem.

Comment: You have to use jQuery validate plugin for this. If you put some code I will provide you a full solution.

Comment: Syed: he clearly mention "I do not want to use the client side validation", he want server side validation

Comment: @SyedNoman - Even if you have client side validation, you always need server side validation as well. Never trust data that comes from the browser...

Comment: You need to make an effort to solve your issue yourself first. _Hint: Ajax._ When you hit a road bump, come back, show us what you got and we might be able to help you. We won't just give you the code, this isn't a coding service.

Comment: You absolutely SHOULD use client side validation -  to pick up simple entry errors / missed fields etc before submitting  the form. What you should NOT do is RELY on client side validation. You MUST use server side validation to prevent poor quality / malicious data being passed into your database / backend, but to ignore client side validation means that a user may have to re-enter form data that they could have more easily been guided to correct prior to form submission. Belts and Suspenders is the way to go. Better to get the data correct before submission. So both client and server side!

Comment: @gavgrif - If he uses Ajax or repopulating the form (which most modern frameworks helps you with), the user doesn't need to re-enter anything. It is, however, better to have client side validation as well since it reduces the amount of unnecessary requests to the back end.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson - yes exactly - my point however was to correct the statement that "client side validation is not safe", which is incorrect and also to say from a UX perspective that to prevent the form from being submitted in the first place until all obvious validation has occurred.

Comment: @magnus Eriksson- Am gonna put up my codes for better clarification